# Musical Notations using Aubio in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, aubio

I am trying to make a program for basic monophonic note transciption using aubio, for my high school class. I am trying to run an example code in Xcode and I get these errors:

Apple Mach-O Linker(Id)Error
"_CFStringCreateWithCString", referenced from:

Any advice on how to fix these errors, or on note transcription using aubio in Xcode would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to add frameworks to your project. For example, _CFStringCreateWithCString is part of the Core Foundation framework. What's the full list of errors?

Comment: (null): "examples_common_del()", referenced from:
(null): "examples_common_init(int, char**)", referenced from:
(null): "examples_common_process(int (*)(fvec_t*, fvec_t*), void (*)())", referenced from:
(null): "_buffer_size", referenced from:
(null): "_examples_common_del", referenced from:
(null): "_examples_common_init", referenced from:

Comment: There are more errors still Apple Mach-O Linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to link against `CoreFoundation`, `AudioToolbox`, and `Accelerate` system frameworks, as well as the [aubio framework](http://aubio.org/download#osx).

Please ask your questions @ https://github.com/aubio/aubio/issues.

Also check out http://www.denemo.org, which does monophonic transcription to score using aubio.